# Homotopy for functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

I am reading [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-036-02/S0002-9939-1972-0334212-5/S0002-9939-1972-0334212-5.pdf) on Homotopy for functors by Ming-Jung 
 Lee.

The author gives a definition (at the beginning of section $3$) as follows :

> Let $\varphi,\varphi':\Lambda\rightarrow \Gamma$ be covariant functors of small categories. We say that $\varphi$ is homotopic to $\varphi'$ if there are covariant functors $\varphi_i:\Lambda\rightarrow \Gamma$ for $i=0,1,\cdots,n$ such that $\varphi_0=\varphi,\varphi_n=\varphi'$ and for each $i$, there is a natural transformation between $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_{i+1}$.

Given two natural transformations, there is an obvious way to compose them which gives a natural transformation.

> What is the point of considering the finite collection of natural transformations between given two functors. We can just define that two functors are homotopic if there is a natural transformation between them.

I do not understand what I am missing. Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: maybe the authors meant that there is a Zig-Zag of natural transformations, but this is just speculation.

Comment: I do not know what is a Zig-Zag of natural transformation.. Do you mean something like $F_0\rightrightarrows F_1\leftleftarrows F_2 \leftleftarrows F_3\rightrightarrows F_4$ where $F_i$ are functors and $\rightrightarrows$  means a natural transformation from right side functor to left side functor and $\leftleftarrows$  means a natural transformation from left side functor to right side functor @HenrikRüping

Comment: @Praphulla Yes. I guess the author means to interpret "there is a natural transformation between $\phi_i$ and $\phi_{i+1}$" without specifying the direction of the natural transformation.

Comment: @MikeMiller Oh. Thanks. It sounds reasonable.

Comment: This question may not need any responce as it is almost clear what the author means. I will wait for some more time and delete the question as this does not really very serious. You can comment if there is anything specific you want to say. Thanks :)

Comment: Given the definition and interpreting it as Mike Miller suggested, there will be a homotopy of the continuous maps of spaces that are the geometric realisation of the given functors, since the geometric realisation of an arbitrary natural transformation is a homotopy (and hence invertible)

Comment: @DavidRoberts It is almost always not easy to understand what you write (may be because English is not my native language).... :D :D Jokes apart, you mean to say : given two functors $F,G:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ you consider their geometric realizations.. I do not completely know what this means, I am just studying about it now.. I only know given a  reasonable category you can associate a topological space called nerve of category and functors between these categories becomes continuous maps between these spaces..

Comment: so, natural transformation should correspond to the notion of homotopy... notion of homotopy is two sided i.e., if $f$ is homotopic to $g$ then $g$ is homotopic to $f$.. So, if there is a notion of homotopy it should be two sided.. In the sense  natural transformation should also be allowed two sided.. so, homotopy is a collection of natural transofrmations where you do not mention from which side to which side you are considering the natural transfromation.. @DavidRoberts This is what you mean right?

Comment: No. A category gives a space, by taking the nerve and then geometric realisation, a functor gives a continuous function, the product of categories is sent to a product of spaces, the category $mathbf{2}$ with two objects and one nontrivial arrow has as its geometric realisation the topological interval, and a natural transformation is sent to a homotopy. The category $\mathbf{2}$ is inherently asymmetric, but its geometric realisation is symmetric under $t\mapsto 1-t$. Given a zig-zag of natural transformations you can get a single homotopy by reversing as needed and then composing them all.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks.. it is little more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to delete this question; I think you could summarize the comments in a community-wiki answer and accept it.

Comment: @MikeShulman thanks for the suggestion. I have given a community wiki answer. I will accept it when I can( there is time limit for two day). Thanks again..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The author means there is a zigzag of natural transformations.   That is, "a natural transformation between $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_{i+1}$" is intended to be nonspecific as to the direction of the transformation: it could go from $\varphi_i$ to $\varphi_{i+1}$ or from $\varphi_{i+1}$ to $\varphi_{i}$.

This is a reasonable notion of "homotopy" between functors because upon passing to geometric realizations / classifying spaces, any natural transformation induces a homotopy in the topological sense, and homotopies in the latter sense can always be reversed as well as composed; thus any zigzag of natural transformations between functors induces a single homotopy between their geometric realizations.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer but too long for a comment!

Though I did not read your mentioned paper https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-036-02/S0002-9939-1972-0334212-5/S0002-9939-1972-0334212-5.pdf in details but what I understood from the  Peter May's answer  here  [Homotopy of functors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349353/homotopy-of-functors?rq=1) that if you define a *homotopy* between 2 covariant functors $F,G :C \rightarrow D$ as a *natural transformation* between them then this notion of "*homotopy*"  **will not induce an expected equivalence relation** on the set of functors from $C$ to $D$. So to solve this problem Ming-jung Lee defined a notion of  "*homotopy*" between $F$ and $G$ as a sequence of covariant functors $\phi_1,....\phi_n:C \rightarrow D$ such that $\phi_1=F$ and $\phi_n=G$ and such that for each $i$ there exists a natural transformation between $\phi_i$ and $\phi_{i+1}$(where the direction of each natural transformation is unspecified). Also as mentioned in corollary 8 in  https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-036-02/S0002-9939-1972-0334212-5/S0002-9939-1972-0334212-5.pdf that if $F$ and $G$ are "*homotopic*" then the induced continuous maps $BF$ and $BG$ between geometric realisations $BC$ and $BD$ of the morphism complexes $MC$ and $MD$ respectively are also homotopic. So the notion of "*homotopy*" as mentioned by Ming-Jung Lee seems reasonable..

Comment: David Roberts said the same in his comments.. Saying something more than once only makes it easier to understand (most of the times)..  So, +1... Thanks for reference to Peter May's answer...